# Getting count of messages in a rabbitmq queue from java code

Tags: java, rabbitmq, message-queue

I am trying to check whether a given rabbitmq queue is empty or not. 
For that i am trying to use:

```
channel.queueDeclarePassive(queueName).getMessageCount().
```

Using this I am always getting 0 as answer irrespective of number of messages shown by `rabbitmqctl` `list_queues`.
There is no API available for this as far as i have searched.

I want same answer as given by `rabbitmqctl` `list_queues`.Please suggest a way to do that.

Comment: Try to use `channel.queueDeclare` instead

Comment: Tried with this also.. no luck.. still giving 0 as answer..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you cannot get messages count using the SDK. channel.queueDeclarePassive(queueName).getMessageCount() is usually not correct because it won't count messages which waiting acknowledges.

you can enable the management plugin and query the queue by REST API:

```
http://localhost:15672/api/queues/vhost/queue_name
```

The response contains the total messages count as well as messages in handling/ready state.
Access to "localhost:15672/api" to see more detail about how to call it.

Here is an example response of it on local server:

```
{
    "memory":14680,
    "message_stats":{
        "publish":1,
        "publish_details":{
            "rate":0
        }
    },
    "messages":1,
    "messages_details":{
        "rate":0
    },
    "messages_ready":1,
    "messages_ready_details":{
        "rate":0
    },
    "messages_unacknowledged":0,
    "messages_unacknowledged_details":{
        "rate":0
    },
    "idle_since":"2014-02-21 18:01:54",
    "policy":"",
    "exclusive_consumer_tag":"",
    "consumers":0,
    "backing_queue_status":{
        "q1":0,
        "q2":0,
        "delta":[
            "delta",
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "q3":0,
        "q4":1,
        "len":1,
        "pending_acks":0,
        "target_ram_count":"infinity",
        "ram_msg_count":1,
        "ram_ack_count":0,
        "next_seq_id":1,
        "persistent_count":0,
        "avg_ingress_rate":0,
        "avg_egress_rate":0,
        "avg_ack_ingress_rate":0,
        "avg_ack_egress_rate":0
    },
    "status":"running",
    "name":"01d99c41-7e08-4122-a7f3-c57d25a460f5",
    "vhost":"/",
    "durable":true,
    "auto_delete":false,
    "arguments":{
    },
    "node":"rabbit@SHACNG109WQPY"
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this, but it doesn't work for me. :( I can open ../api , also ../api/queues , but ../api/queues/vhost and ../api/queues/vhost/queue_name no. Do you know what can I try to make this work? You mentioned ,,you can enable the management plugin'' what his mean? Thanks!

Comment: `http://localhost:15672/api/queues/%2f/hello` - where 'hello' queue name, and '/' - vhost name

Answer (score 0):

Use following url to access details via http api,

`http://public-domain-name:15672/api/queues/%2f/queue_name`

or use following command from localhost cli promt,

`curl -i -u guest_uname:guest_password http://localhost:15672/api/queues/%2f/queue_name`

Where, 
%2f is default vhost "/"